# Meaning of $\langle 0 | \hat{H} | 0 \rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, ground-state

If $\hat{H}$ is a Hamiltonian or any other operator in matrix form, what is the meaning of:

$$\langle 0 | \hat{H} | 0 \rangle$$

Comment: The meaning is the vacuum energy. It really depends on your Hamiltonian

Comment: What do you mean by |0>? Do you mean the ground state energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you have is a quantum system in the state $|0\rangle$, then the meaning of $\langle 0|\hat M|0\rangle$ where $\hat M$ is an operator corresponding to an arbitrary observable depends on whether the state $|0\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the operator $\hat M$.

1. If $|0\rangle$ *is* an eigenstate of the operator $\hat M$ then the action of $\hat M$ on $|0\rangle$ is to multiply it by a constant (the eigenvalue)$^1$: $$\langle0|\hat M|0\rangle=\langle0|m|0\rangle=m\langle0|0\rangle=m \tag{1}.$$ This shouldn't be surprising since $\langle0|\hat M|0\rangle$ is the expectation value of a measurement of $\hat M$ if the system is in the state $|0\rangle$, and if we *know* that $|0\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat M$ then these measurements can only yield one possible value, $m$.
2. If $|0\rangle$ is *not* an eigenstate of $\hat M$ (which it doesn't *have* to be, even if $\hat M$ is an observable), then this equation is the expectation value of $\hat M$ in the state $|0\rangle$. Note that the action of $\hat M$ on a general state is *not* just a rescaling as was the case with its eigenvectors.

If we're talking about the Hamiltonian operator, $\hat H$, then $|0\rangle$ will (in usual notation) be the lowest energy state (note that this *doesn't* imply the energy itself is zero). In this case your equation will give: $$\langle0|\hat H|0\rangle=\langle0|E_0|0\rangle=E_0\langle0|0\rangle=E_0. \tag{2}$$

---

$^1$ Note that we have assumed the state is normalised, so $\langle0|0\rangle=1.$

Comment: Why does $\langle0|\hat M|0\rangle$ "not mean anything" if $|0\rangle$ is not an eigenstate of $\hat{M}$? As you stated in 1, $\langle0|\hat M|0\rangle$ represents the expectation value of $\hat{M}$, given that you're in state $|0\rangle$ - this seems like it has a meaningful interpretation whether or not you're in an eigenstate of $\hat{M}$.

Comment: @Shrey You are right, I will update the answer thanks.